# PyQGIS: GDAL hillshade patchwork effect

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, hillshade

I have used QGIS to batch import and visualise tiled elevation data. This is illuminated greyscale, with identical parameters used each time, so I would have expected the result to be seamless and the tile boundaries to be essentially invisible.

However, the result is a 'patchwork quilt' effect. The shading is not consistent from one tile to the next. I do not understand why not. This is the code used to apply the hillshading:

```
  def ShadeRaster(raster, pth):

    import processing   

    parameters = {'INPUT': "", 
      'BAND': 1, 
      'COMPUTE_EDGES': False,
      'ZEVENBERGEN': False,
      'Z_FACTOR': 1.0,
      'SCALE': 1.0,
      'AZIMUTH': 315,
      'COMBINED': False,
      'ALTITUDE': 45,
      'MULTIDIRECTIONAL': False,
      'OUTPUT': ""}

    parameters['INPUT'] =raster.name()
    parameters['OUTPUT'] = pth + '/' + raster.name() + '.tif'

    processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:hillshade',parameters,feedback=feedback)
    return QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Hillshade')[0]
```

As you can see, the elevation and azimuth of the light source are always the same. But this is how it looks:

[image]

Why?

Comment: What software are you viewing this in? Is each tile a unique file or is the hillshade a mosaic? It looks to me like the tiles are single images which have been stretched by default, if you mosaic or build a VRT of the hillshade tiles the contrast stretch should be applied over all the tiles the same.

Comment: It is viewed in QGIS. The code shown above generates a TIFF image for each tile, and it is at this point that the inconsistent shading occurs. Agreed, it does look as if the contrast is being stretched, but I am not sure why or how to prevent it. Once generated I dragged and dropped the images into QGIS with the result as shown.

Comment: ArcMap does the same thing, I suggest creating a VRT with GDALBuildVRT (from the command line). A VRT is an XML file that points to your existing raster so is fast to create and takes up only a little space then add the VRT to your QGIS project. Your other option is to go to each hillshade tile layer and turn the stretching off in the layer properties, I think it's MIN-MAX or 'standard deviations' by default; because each tile has different statistics the stretched values do not match.

Comment: Thanks for the info ; I will investigate. First option wouldn't necessarily work since the hillshading is done within a plugin and should be fully automatic. Turning off stretching for each raster layer (before generating images) sounds like a better bet. I could presumably automate that.

Comment: Seems I need to set the contrast enhancement for the raster layer to 'no enhancement' before running the hillshading.

Comment: Does that work? If so that would make a good answer to your own question.

Comment: I think it probably will, but no I have not got it to work as yet. Available Python code examples seem limited and I haven't had time to do much R&D.

Comment: I run the tool on the command line but if you must use python the subprocess.Popen() function might be what you need.. command line arguments are (Windows) pcs = subprocess.Popen([r'c:\full\path\to\gdal\GDALBuildVRT',r'c:\full\path\to\output.vrt',r'c:\full\path\to\your\hillshade\tiles\\*.tif']) then pcs.wait() # wait until done, there are more advanced options if you need https://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html

Answer (score 1):

OK... Got it. I changed approach a little bit, having realised that I don't have to run the Hillshade algorithm and generate a TIFF. I can just apply hillshade rendering to the memory raster layer.

I have now got a three stage process (repeated for each grid tile):

1. Create raster layer from xyz ASCII file
2. Set contrast enhancement to 'none'
3. Set render to 'hillshade'

Stages 2 and 3 can actually be done via the QGIS GUI quite easily and applied to multiple layers, but I have done it programmatically.

```
def ImportRaster(self, raster):

  from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo

  fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
  path = fileInfo.filePath()
  baseName = fileInfo.baseName()

  layer = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)
  QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

  return layer if layer.isValid() else None

def setNoEnhancement(self, layer): # set contrast enhancement to 'no enhancement'
  ContrastEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement.NoEnhancement
  myBand = layer.renderer().grayBand()
  myType = layer.renderer().dataType(myBand)
  myEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement(myType)
  myEnhancement.setContrastEnhancementAlgorithm(ContrastEnhancement, True)
  layer.renderer().setContrastEnhancement(myEnhancement)

def setRenderHillshade(self, layer): # set render type to 'hillshade'
  r = QgsHillshadeRenderer(layer.dataProvider(), 1, 315, 45)
  layer.setRenderer(r)

def XYZToShadedTIFF(self, fname):

  l = self.ImportRaster(fname) # import file, return layer 'l'

  if not l is None:
    self.setNoEnhancement(l) # ContrastEnhancement to 'none'
    self.setRenderHillshade(l) # hillshade
```

This works.

Thanks Michael for the assistance.